# Displaying Trees in Arc Scene

Tags: 3d, arcscene, display

I'm new to ArcScene. I'm using a historic map, in ArcMap, to draw old roads, garden plots and tree locations. My trees are in a point shapefile in ArcMap, I brought them into ArcScene and I'm trying to figure out how I can display them in a way that is true to their height.

Can you provide a step-by-step instructional guide on how to do this? I used the surface elevations of my DEM to assign ZM values (see Z column). I also assigned an arbitrary 20ft value to each tree (see Z-offset column).

[image: Snapshot]

I think I have all of the correct information in my ZM tree shapefile but I'm just not using the correct tools to display what I need to display. I've searched for a couple of days online and can't find anything.

I noticed in your "How to correctly display trees in ArcScene" that your snapshot showed trees of different sizes. Hoping you can assist.

PS do you know of any additional tutorials I could use for this project? Web forums, youtube videos, books, etc. I would like to use ArcScene for future projects, this is my first. All future projects of interest would be created in the same way- bringing in a map or aerial, adding buildings (currently from sketchup), adding landscape features like trees, water and roads.

Comment: So, when you put this shapefile in ArcScene, does it automatically use the elevations in the Z column for initial placement?  After that, you want all points raised 20 ft?